# How to change permission in Django view sub-class?

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following setup right now:

```
class MyView(MyPermission1, MyPermission2, FormView):
    ...

class MyChildView(MyView):
   ...
```

The child view is inheriting from the parent, but I want to remove `MyPermission1` and `MyPermission2` from it and apply another class called `MyPermissionChild`. Is there a way to do this using the generic views available in Django?

Comment: Normally in that case you write `MyView` as a mixin, and in that cases you can thus define your `MyChildView` as `MyChildView(MyMixin, FormView)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you elaborate a bit more? What if I need the `MyView` to work as a regular view as well? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: then you make a `MyViewMixin`, and then you can define a `MyView(MyViewMixin, MyPermission1, MyPermission2, FormView)`, and a `MyChildView(MyViewMixin, FormView)`. In the mixin you thus override the items you want to override for any view that will inherit the mxin.

Comment: Woudn't `MyView(MyPermission1, MyPermission2, FormView)` and `MyChildView(MyPermissionChild, FormView)` do the job?

Comment: @JPG Honestly not even sure about this one.